# SQL Group By Cube and get total of each combination

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a question about using Group by Cube option in T-SQL. I am using SQL Server 2012.

So I have a table like below:

```
UserID  | A | B | C | D
------------------------
  1     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  2     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  3     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
  4     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  5     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  6     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  7     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
  8     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  9     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  10    | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  11    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  12    | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1
  13    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
  14    | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  15    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
  16    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
  17    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  18    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  19    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
  20    | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
  21    | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
  22    | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Using Group By Cube on A,B,C and D, I get 15 combinations excluding the empty set. Now, I want to find how many users fall under each combination. If no user has one such combination, I still want to to see the combination but the column with count of users can be zero. so the result output should be

```
A   B   C   D   Qty
1               0
    1           0
        1       0
            1   0
1   1           7
1       1       0
1           1   0
1   1   1       5
1   1   1   1   7
    1   1       0
    1       1   0
    1   1   1   2
        1   1   1
1   1       1   0
1       1   1   0
```

Any way I can achieve this? Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to create a table with all possibilities and use a `LEFT JOIN` against the normal `GROUP BY` you would do.

If this is for an occasional run, maybe the temporary table might be okay. If not, a permanent table would be best so you are not constantly creating and dropping the temporary table.

```
/* Create a temporary table */
CREATE TABLE TEMPSO11052016 (A int, B int, C int, D int);

/* Insert all possibilities on the temporary table */
INSERT INTO TEMPSO11052016 (A, B, C, D)
VALUES (1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,0,1),(1,0,1,1),(0,1,1,1),
       (1,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0),(1,0,0,1),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1),
       (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,0);

/* Run the selection query */
SELECT T.A, T.B, T.C, T.D, ISNULL(CT, 0)         
FROM TEMPSO11052016 T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A, B, C, D, COUNT(ID) AS CT FROM SO11052016 GROUP BY A, B, C, D) S
ON S.A=T.A AND S.B=T.B AND S.C=T.C AND S.D=T.D;

/* Drop the temporary table */
DROP TABLE TEMPSO11052016;
```

Comment: Perfect! I need this for a report that will be generated periodically. I created a permanent table with the combinations. This works perfectly. Thank you so much, @Edu

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Edu's response, but using cross joins to create the "all combinations" table.

```
; with CTE as (select '' as Value
               union all
               select '1')
, CTE2 as (Select a.Value as A, b.Value as B, c.Value as C, d.Value as D  
                    from CTE a
                    cross join CTE b
                    cross join CTE c
                    cross join CTE d)

select a.*, count(distinct b.UserID) from CTE2 a
left join #mydata b
on a.a = b.a and a.b = b.b and a.c = b.c and a.d = b.d
group by a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D
order by a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) This works without any need for creating a permanent table.